# Combining Scores in R

Tags: r

I am trying to combine scores referring to APOE e4 status.
0 equals no e4 alleles,
1 equals 1 allele
2 equals 2 alleles
I want to combine 1 and 2 so they represent 1 (apoe present) and 0 (apoe not present) so I can use this as an interaction term.

How do I do this? It seems very easy but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no missing values and we only have values 0, 1, and 2. Check if allele is bigger than 0, then convert to integer:

```
#example data
set.seed(1); x <- sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
x
# [1] 0 2 0 1 0 2 2 1 1 2

as.integer(x > 0)
# [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```